# Как разместить кнопки на картинке и текст?

Tags: html, java, css, javascript

Как разместить кнопки на картинке и текст?

Comment: То есть вы xотите, чтобы у вас на изображении сверxу помещалась кнопка и текст? И причем здесь Java?

Comment: Это же ведь возможно селать с помощью разных технологий

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего через CSS. Задаете относительное позиционирование:

```
<div style="background-image:url('img.png'); width: 100px; height: 100px">
    <div style="position: relative; top: 10px; left: 30px">ОЛОЛО</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот как:

```
<center>
    <h3>Реклама</h3>
    <form><input img="картинка.jpg acton="реклама.php" />
    </form>
</center>
```