# Как поставить button на image?

Tags: html, css, html5

я новичок в HTML и хочу поставить кнопку на картинку(без нарушений адаптивности), но все что я нашел это `position: absolute`
Вот мой код html

```
<div class="section2">
    <div class="wedo">
        <div class="wedo__item" >
            <img src="Mobile.png" class="smart">
        </div>
        <div class="wedo__item2">
            <button>Скачать</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И вот css

```
.section2{
    margin-top: 4.3rem;

}

.wedo {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.wedo_item {
    width: 50%
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
   .wedo__item {
    width: 100%;
    } 
}


/*.smart {
    margin-left: 5.4rem;
}*/
@media(max-width: 768px) {


    .smart {
        height: 300px;
        margin-left: 2.4rem;
    }
}

.wedo__item2 {
    height: fit-content;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    right: 0;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Под нарушением адаптивности я имею ввиду то, что кнопка "гуляет" по изображению

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как разместить кнопки на картинке и текст?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18104/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82)

Comment: Этот способ более менее работает, но при переходе из мобильной версии сайта в  компьютерную все съезжает, да и мне бы еще понять как работает такой способ

Comment: Можете посмотреть вот тут, если это то, что нужно. [Пуф](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8683553/17025310)

Comment: Здравствуйте, в методе который вы отправили просто меняют изображение на кнопке, а я ищу другое